# How to use a function after definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to make a program which calculates how many kilometers a ship passes in one day.

It should look like this:

```
def journey():
    journey_calc = speed * 1852 / 1000 * 24
    journey_calc = round(journey_calc)
    return journey

speed = 5
print("Ship passes: " + str(journey) + " kilometers in one day")
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Pass `speed` into the function.  What isn't working about your code?  You may want to put parentheses around the denominator in your `journey_calc` arithmetic

Comment: @EliKorvigo No it doesn't.  It returns the `journey` function object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly `speed` is a parameter for the function, so pass it to the function as an argument, not via a global variable.

```
def journey(knots):
    '''Convert knots to kilometres per day'''
    return round(knots * 1.852 * 24)

>>> speed = 5    # in knots
>>> print("Ship travels {} kilometres in one day".format(journey(speed)))
Ship travels 222 kilometres in one day
>>> print(journey(10))
444
```

The key thing to know is that you *call* the function which is achieved by using the parentheses, `()`. Any arguments that you need to pass to the function are listed in the parentheses, in this case a single argument named `knots`. So, to call the function use `journey(5)` to pass `5` as the value of the `knots` argument. You can use variables names to pass values to the function, i.e. `journey(speed)` will pass the value of `speed` to the function.

If you want to remember the value returned by a function you can assign it to a variable:

```
>>> distance = journey(10)
>>> distance
444
```

Answer (score 0):

on the code write this when you want to call it. you have to define it first though. journey cannot be a variable, as it is already a function.

```
journey()
```